# Dynamic data retrieval upon selection (state change)?

Tags: next.js13, react-server-components

I'm using NextJS 14, and I want to set up something like this:

I have two sections on my page. The left one lists products, and when a product is selected, I want the right section to show detailed info about that product. How can I fetch this detailed information from a database when a product is selected?

What are some ways to achieve this using the new paradigm?